# iAd Crashing in 3.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm noticing my iAd is causing a crash on iOS 3.2.  I am weak linking in the build settings.  It crashes in my createAdBanner method

```
NSString *contentSize;

if (&ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait != nil) {
    contentSize = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation) ? ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait : ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
}
else {
    contentSize = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation) ? ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50 : ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32;
}
```

Here is the error that comes up.

```
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
        Attaching to process 4681.
        Assertion failed: (cls), function getName, file /SourceCache/objc4_Sim/objc4-427.1.1/runtime/objc-runtime-new.m, line 3939.
        Assertion failed: (cls), function getName, file /SourceCache/objc4_Sim/objc4-427.1.1/runtime/objc-runtime-new.m, line 3939.
        Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
        (gdb)
```

I thought you were able to run iAds on 3.2 if you weak linked.  Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from weak-linking, you must check if the ad classes are available on the device. To do so, you can use the following to test for the existence of a class:

```
Class adClass = NSClassFromString(@"AdBannerView");

if(adClass){
  //ads are available so optionally show them
}else{
  // ads are not available 
}
```

To check for a particular method, you would use this:

```
BOOL methodExists = [someObject respondsToSelector:@selector(selectorToTestName:)];

if(methodExists){
   //Safe to call selector
}else{
   //The selector doesn't exist in this version of iOS. 
}
```

You could also just use the above statement, "inlining" the boolean check:

```
if([someObject respondsToSelector:@selector(selectorToTestName:)]){
   //Safe to call selector
}else{
   //The selector doesn't exist in this version of iOS. 
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error can this be done in viewdidload?  Especially the Class adClass = ... where should that be put.

Comment: @Vikings1201 - What error are you getting? This code should work in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Okay I fixed the error, however it never goes into the if part of the statement if there could be ads.  So ads are never displayed.

Comment: Never mind the class is ADBannerView, not AdBannerView.  It works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

ADBannerView is available in 4.0 or later.

You won't be able to show ads in 3.2

Comment: No it is not!  You need to weak link the framework and code around it in 3.2

Comment: @Vikings1201 - See my answer as to how to code around weak-linked frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

ADBannerViewcan be used in 4.0 and above. See the apple documentation

Answer (score 0):

use below link it is giving more clearly even to use in ios 3.0+ [IAD Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app) you have to import _weak_framework iAd in the linkingFlags wich is available in the targets.Once go through the link.